# HttpResponseRedirect have extra path and fail

Tags: django

This is my code:

views.py

```
def monthly_challenges_by_number(request,month):
    months = list(monthly_challenges.keys())
    redirect_month = months[month-1]
    return HttpResponseRedirect("challenges/" + redirect_month)

def monthly_challenge(request,month):
    try:
        content_text = monthly_challenges[month]
        return HttpResponse(content_text)
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("this is not supported!!")
```

challenges/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("<int:month>", views.monthly_challenges_by_number),
    path("<str:month>", views.monthly_challenge),

]
```

monthly_challenges/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("challenges/",include("challenges.urls"))
]
```

error :
Not Found: /challenges/challenges/february

```
Using the URLconf defined in monthly_challenges.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    challenges/ <int:month>
    challenges/ <str:month>

The current path, challenges/challenges/february, didn’t match any of these.
```

I am following a Django course and follow his code, but I don't know why HttpResponseRedirect is two challenges?

Comment: Add ```/``` at the end of  urls in challenges/urls.py

Answer (score 0):

As per here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect

It should have been this: `return HttpResponseRedirect("/challenges/" + redirect_month)`